# What is the quickest and version generic way to do a group by sum in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Let's assume I am using any of 3 versions of excel: 2016, 2010 and 2007. I want a method that works in all these versions, where I don't have to think different ways of doing it.

And I want to be able to copy paste the results, particularly the result should be row-oriented group by sum result, similar to what one might typically get from a SQL GROUP BY query.

Is the quickest way, pivot table, subtotals or some other method?

And how do you get there? Shortcut keys or Menu or some other way?

As an example, if I have this data:

```
Fa Fb Fc
a 4 10
b 3 1
a 5 2
```

I want to get the following on a group by Fa:

```
Fa SumFb SumFc
a 9 12
b 3 1
```

Comment: The question would be more understandable if you edit it to explain what you mean by "copy paste row-oriented group by sum result".

Comment: @Blackwood done. Hopefully that is good?

Comment: That's a bit better. I'm still not clear what you mean, but perhaps others will understand.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking, but any method that works in Excel 2007 should work in the newer versions

Comment: Office 365 is not a version, it is a service that *delivers the latest version* of Office products. Currently the version it delivers is Excel 2016.

Comment: @SirAdelaide, I'm asking if there is version generic method where the actual steps to be performed are exactly the same.

Comment: The problem is that "row-oriented group by sum result" doesn't mean anything to most of us. You ask if you can get the same result with a pivot table, but we don't know what you're trying to achieve so can't answer the question. Maybe add images of your spreadsheet, or give examples of the data you are working with.

Comment: "What is the quickest way" this sounds too subjective, it depends on a lot of things including personal preferences. How big is your data? How often you change it? Do you overwrite the whole dataset / create a new file / just change some values...? These all influence the solution. As others mentioned, There is no new functionality since Excel 2007 which would make any difference to your solution.

Comment: "What is the quickest way" - asking such a question I'd think you've already tried some of them and have the experience and you can share what are the paint points for each of them, so we can suggest improvements.

Comment: @SirAdelaide, I have added an example

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly classic Pivot table.